# how to get a total number of properties(nodes,relationships) and list of all properties(nodes,relationships) in neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to get a total number of properties `(nodes,relationships)` and list of all properties(nodes,relationships)  in neo4j database.

When we create nodes and relationships in neo4j database, we get message like this below "`Added 24 labels, created 24 nodes, set 70 properties, created 45 relationships, completed after 31 ms.`"

I like to validate the properties created. Hence I want to know how to query for list of the properties created in database.

Comment: You can return the list of properties in the create query. Can you share your create query here?

Answer (score 1):

For a broad summary of labels, relationships and properties in use, along with a global total of nodes and relationships, click on the database icon in the top left corner of Neo4j Browser.

For more in-depth statistics you may find

```
CALL apoc.meta.data()
```

useful. You will need to install [APOC](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/) first